# Im giving margin-left for my <th>...but it isn´t working

Tags: html, css

Im trying to have a table that have some `<th>` and `.

And I want to give a margin-left to my scond table header, so I have a class margin in my second `th`.

But its not working, Im not getting any margin.

I have here my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xnwtqLsc/4/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <th>Test Title 1</th>
        <th class="margin">Test Title 2</th>
        <th>Test Title 3</th>
        <th>Test Title 4</th>
        <tr>
            <td>Test 1.1</td>
            <td>Test 1.2</td>
            <td>Test 1.3</td>
            <td>Test 1.4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    width:1000px;
    background:#ccc;
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background:red;
    height:40px;
}
table th.margin{
    margin-left:350px;
}
```

Comment: Table cells don't use margins, try using padding instead, or giving the desired width the first column

Comment: i guess your th elements are for header isn't it? put them in <tr>

Comment: Thank you, it worked with padding instead of margin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will also need to add `display: block` to the CSS of `table th.margin` if you want to use `margin-left`, like this:

```
table th.margin{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 350px;
}
```

Although I'd recommend you to use `padding-left` instead:

```
table th.margin{
    padding-left: 350px;
}
```